# Installing gcc on rhel 6.1

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, rhel

GCC doesnt seem to be installed on my Rhel 6.1 machine. Also, when i did:

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

It barfed:

```
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package gcc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

The same command works fine on rhel 5.5. What could be the problem?

Update:

```
sudo yum search gcc
```

Returns:

```
libgcc.x86_64 : GCC version 4.4 shared support library
libgomp.x86_64 : GCC OpenMP v3.0 shared support library

sudo yum grouplist
```

Returns:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Group Process
Error: No group data available for configured repositories


sudo  yum install repolist
```

Returns:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package repolist available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Update 2:

```
sudo yum repolist
```

Returns:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
repolist: 0
```

Comment: Odd.  What does `yum repolist` tell you?  What about `yum search gcc`?  On CentOS 5.6, I see a package called "gcc.i386"; maybe that's the one you need to install.

Comment: I have updated the question with needed output

Comment: `yum repolist`, not `yum grouplist`.  Incidentally, I likely won't be able to answer your question, but someone else who's more familiar with RHEL probably will with the additional information.

Comment: `yum repolist`, *not* `yum install repolist`

Comment: I have updated it with the output from yum repolist

Comment: Wouldn't that be a better question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)? (I have the same problem right now by the way, but didn't have time to dig deeper)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by switch from rhn to (more commonly available sources) centos.

1. Remove "yum-rhn-plugin" package from RHEL, this is used to check
   the activation in RHEL.

`rpm -e yum-rhn-plugin`

2. Remove the "redhat-release" related packages, this is used to check
   the repositories compatibility. usually we can't remove these packages
   because they are used by other packages of the system for proper
   fuctioning. so we'll use the "--nodeps" parameter to forcely remove
   them from the system.

`rpm -e redhat-release-notes-5Server redhat-release-5Server --nodeps`

3. Download & install the "centos-release" relates packages, to fill
   in the gap that we made by removing the "redhat-release" related
   packages.

http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-5-11.el5.centos.i386.rpm
http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-notes-5.11-0.i386.rpm

4. To automatically inform about the updates in GUI, in `/etc/yum/yum-updatesd.conf` add the following under the section "# how to send notifications"

`dbus_listener = yes`

5. To change the OS name in the CLI login, edit `/etc/issue`. Since we have installed the "centos-release" relates packages, the OS name will come as "CentOS release 5 (Final)", so delete it and type:

`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga)` (Or any name you like)

6. And now run;

`yum updates`